# PYTHON - How do I separate a column into two columns based on a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I need to separate de causaaveria column into two columns.
So that I have the description (string) in one column and the number on the other.

```
idalarmas   fkidparque  tag             naerogenerador  causaaveria                   
4670459     G1037       G1037_001_4_0   A0201           17516 Wtg running limited by P-F tool
```

Expected result:

```
idalarmas   fkidparque  tag             naerogenerador  event     causaaveria                     
4670459     G1037       G1037_001_4_0   A0201           17516     Wtg running limited by P-F tool
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO; glad you found an answer that works for you. As a contributor to the site, consider adding a [mre] in this and future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['event','causaaveria']]=df['causaaveria'].str.split(' ',1,expand=True)
```

Comment: Great! I did it before, but didn't add the 1 for it to count only one space. Thanks!